# Video playback using Totem/Gnome Videos fails because of missing "vaapipostproc" GStreamer module

Tags: gnome, video, totem

I am having issues playing videos using Totem/Gnome Videos in Ubuntu 23.04. When launching with normal videos files (mkv container, h264 video, aac audio), I get an error message complaining about missing GStreamer module "vaapipostproc". (see attached image)

The message allows me to search the software library for it, but this does not yield any results.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnFuR.png)

I checked and have installed extra gstreamer plugins (gstreamer1.0-plugins-*), as well as gstreamer1.0-vaapi.

Any advice on how to get this working?

Comment: try "rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/"

Comment: Thanks, however it had no effect, error message remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Does your PC use an NVidia GPU? I had the same issue and installing `nvidia-vaapi-driver` solved it for me:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-vaapi-driver
```